# Replace a string only from a specific line , While string occurs in multiple lines via ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

Currently my  /etc/default/grub looks like this :

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/rhel-swap rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rd.lvm.lv=rhel/swap rhgb quiet selinux=0 idle=poll isolcpus=2-4 intel_idle.max_cstate=1 nosoftlookup nohalt nmi_watchdog=0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" isolcpus=2-4"
```

I need to remove the isolcpus=2-4 only from 6th line , but the last line should stay as it is . So far I have been unable to do so . What ever I have tried removes it from both the lines . 
Need to do it via ansible only .

Edit : The expected output should look like :

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/rhel-swap rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rd.lvm.lv=rhel/swap rhgb quiet selinux=0 idle=poll  intel_idle.max_cstate=1 nosoftlookup nohalt nmi_watchdog=0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" isolcpus=2-4"
```

Comment: Hi. You are asking to remove something from a line (second declaration of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX) which should also stay as it is (this is the last line of you file). Can you please clarify ? The easiest way is probably to edit you question and show what you expect exactly. Moreover, can you please also show => `What ever I have tried`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if everything is fixed like you said, but you can use

```
sed '6 s/isolcpus=2-4//' /etc/default/grub
```

add -i if you like what you get :)

Comment: You'll want to put the space in front of `isol` to avoid it matching `fredisol` which wouldn't be the intention, and IMHO the line number is unnecessarily specific

Comment: There's no need to do fancy things for a specific usage that is matched against

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way you can achieve it using `lineinmodule`.

```sh
   - name: line replace
     lineinfile:
       path: /etc/default/grub
       regexp: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" isolcpus=2-4"'
       line: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" "'
```

Comment: Watch out, the presence of `$` in `regexp` means something specific and should be escaped, either with a backslash or in a character class: `=[$]GRUB_CMD`. Please also fix the indentation of your yaml